# Email is not sent in to registered customer in magento 1.9

Tags: php, email, magento, magento-1.9.1

I am using Magento 1.9.1. But email is not working here.

When a registered user place an order, order confirmation email is not sent to customer. But when someone post an order as a guest, the order confirmation email is sending.

Comment: you should upgrade your questions, show details of the errors

Comment: no errors is showing, but don't receive the confirmation email when posting an order as a registered user, but work fine when post order as a guest.

Comment: Have you added any content within New Order template?

Answer (score 0):

all your transactional emails are properly configured?

The settings in System - Settings - General - Contact correct?

The settings in System - Configuration - Sales - E-mail sales, correct?

After checking the above, use this module and make the SMTP settings

[SMTP Pro](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

the following may be useful. when using the Soap to register clients, the modified email is sent as follows. \ app \ code \ core \ Mage \ Customer \ Model \ Customer / Api.php

Line 64 will find `public function create($customerData) { $customerData = $this->_prepareData($customerData); try { $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer') ->setData($customerData) ->save();`

Place the following often. `$customer->sendNewAccountEmail("registered","",1);`

This will send the mail.